# Change red color of setError to blue?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm using the `EditText.setError` method to setErrors when the user gives bad input. The problem is that the red color deviates from my apps style. Is there any way to change the red to another color? Do I need to sneak through the source-code, find the files, take em, edit em then use em as my own?

Comment: The resource used by android is internal. I don't see any easy way to change this.

Comment: I think the only way is to create your own custom EditText (extend from TextView) and override setError()